# How to correctly link winsock2.h in C?

Tags: c, windows, qt, sockets

I'm using QT Creator to build a C plain project. My project inlcudes a socket creation and I'm getting many errors of reference.

My code is simple:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
undefined reference to `_imp__socket@12'
undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
```

Then I suppose this means that `winsock2.h` lib is not included. How to do this without `#pragma comment()`?

Comment: @a3f Thanks for alerting! I just checked the answer and it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#include <winsock2.h>` usage is fine.  It's that you need to update your project settings and add `ws2_32.lib` as a link library.

**For Qt**, just add this line to your .pro file.  Assumes you are using a Microsoft compiler:

```
LIBS += ws2_32.lib
```

Note: I had to actually delete the "build" directory from the command line and then do a "clean build" from Qt Creator for the change to take effect.

Comment: Visual Studio project?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the `Qt` tag.... I'll fix that shortly....

Comment: Yeah! This solution works